# ls: cannot access '/etc/supervisord/conf.d/': Operation not permitted

Tags: python, docker, shell

I'm building a docker image and in Dockerfile, I have mentioned commands as shown below:

(showing only snippet of my Dockerfile)

```
FROM python:bullseye \
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
COPY GW_supervisord_qaprd.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf \
RUN ls -lhtra /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

When I run docker build command to build image with mentioned base image, image build process gets failed and it throws an error when executes last RUN command.

**Error is: "ls: cannot access '/etc/supervisord/conf.d/': Operation not permitted"**

But when I change the FROM image to "FROM python:3.6-stretch" then it does not throw any error.

Is it because that access to this directory needs a privileged access and needs to access with sudo?

Can someone help me underderstand?

Thanks in advance.